# Using Google Script, how do I exclude a word when using regex to search for other words within a given word limit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Very inexperienced coder here, I have a script that uses regex to search for words within a word limit, such as find `word1` and `word2` within 10 words of each other. Then it prints the results into a spreadsheet. However, I am trying to figure out how to include exclusion criteria into my script, such as find `word1` and `word2` within 10 words of each other if `word3` does not occur within those 10 words. I think I managed to include the exclusion criteria using negative lookahead, but when I do, the word limit doesn't work anymore. Here is my script:

```
function regexwithsheetpop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results1');
  var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues(); 
  var regexp = /^((?!dispute).)*([\W*(the)\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(account)])$|^((?!dispute).)*([(account)\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(the)])$/i;
  var result = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    var row = data[i];
    var column = row[0];
    if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
        result.push(row);
    }
  }
  if (result.length > 0) {
    var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheetDataRows === 1 ? resultsSheetDataRows : resultsSheetDataRows + 1; 
    var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(resultsSheetDataRows, 1, result.length, 3);
    resultsSheetRange.setValues(result);
  }
}
```

Here is my working code without the exclusion criteria:

```
function regexwithsheetpop() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('run,use,card');
var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues(); 
var regexp = /\W*(account)\W*\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(the)|(the)\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(account)/i;
var result = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
     var row = data[i];
     var column = row[0];
     if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
        result.push(row); }}
if (result.length > 0) {
    var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheetDataRows === 1 ? resultsSheetDataRows : resultsSheetDataRows + 1; 
    var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(resultsSheetDataRows, 1, result.length, 3);
  resultsSheetRange.setValues(result);}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "within 10 word of each other"? And example/screenshot of your data in Sheet 1 would be appreciated. Do you want to copy rows where the first column contains the word 'account' and 'the' but not 'dispute'?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give a screenshot of my data as it is confidential, but yes I want to copy rows where the first column contains "account" and "the" but not "dispute". However, "account" and "the" should occur within 10 words of each other. For instance, "**account** word1 word2 word3 **the**" would print but "**account** word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 **the**" would not print. And it would not print if dispute occurred within those 10 words, e.g., "**account** word1 word2 **dispute** word3 word4 **the**" would not print. Apologies if this isn't clear.

Comment: Can you provide your working code before you added the exclusion criteria?

Comment: Just added my working code without the exclusion criteria

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer, it should work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know either a certain word is contained in a cell or not, you do not need Regex

### Much easier is the use of [IndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Sample:

```
if(column.indexOf("dispute")!=-1){
  Logger.log("Column contains dispute");
  }
else if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
  result.push(row); 
}
```

Thereby, you do not need to incorporate "dispute" into your `regexp` definition.

Applying it to your code:

```
function regexwithsheetpop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results1');     //mind the name
  var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues(); 
  var regexp = /\W*(account)\W*\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(the)|(the)\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(account)/i;
  var result = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
     var row = data[i];
     var column = row[0];
     if(column.indexOf("dispute")!=-1){
       Logger.log("Column in row "+(i+1)+" contains dispute");
     } else if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
        result.push(row); }
  }
  if (result.length > 0) {
     var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
     resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheetDataRows === 1 ? resultsSheetDataRows : resultsSheetDataRows + 1; 
     var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(resultsSheetDataRows, 1, result.length, 3);
     resultsSheetRange.setValues(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, where would I add this to the working code I have? I have tried but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a snippet of where I added it: 
```var result = [];   
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
     var row = data[i];
     var column = row[0];
  
    if(column.indexOf("dispute")!=-1){
      Logger.log("dispute");
    }
    else if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
      result.push(row); 
  
if (result.length > 0) {```

Comment: Replace your working code with the one in my answer. In your comment, you are missing `}}` before `if (result.length > 0) `